# bitnami/kubectl container unable to create files - permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, bitnami

I have used "bitnami/kubectl:latest" image to my test container which runs inside a test pod. I just login to that container and I wanted to create a file inside that container. But ended up with below error.

```
I have no name!@test:/$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
I have no name!@test:/$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory 'test': Permission denied
```

Can someone help me to understand why this problem occurs and how to fix this? I am aware that mounting the file as configmap might help me but just I need to understand this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're in the root directory (`/`), but you're running as a non-root user, so of course you don't have permissions to create files there. You can probably create files in `/tmp`, or you could mount a volume somewhere on the filesystem and you would probably have write access there as well.

Comment: @larsks Thanks creating it in /tmp helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the docker image which you are using is configured to run its final instruction using a non-root user (`USER 1001` in this case).

Have a look at the Dockerfile instruction:
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kubectl/blob/master/1.24/debian-11/Dockerfile#L24

So you can either

- create files in a non-root user owned directory like `/tmp` or
- create your own docker image after removing that `USER 1001` instruction from the Dockerfile and host it in your own repository which can then be pulled into your cluster.

Whatever works for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: since the repository of bitnami/kubectl has changed, the new repo is https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/kubectl/1.28/debian-12/Dockerfile